# node js request promise, scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm scraping a website , i use request library with node js, so I got an array of urls I loop through and do a request on each, the problem is that requests are asynchronous and I need to do something ONLY after all the requests are completed here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

        request(urls[i], function (err,resp,body) {

            if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                var string = $('.author .mini').text();
                var regExp = /(\+971|00971|05)\d{1,12}/g;
                if(string.match(regExp)) {mobilePhones.push(string.match(regExp)[0])}



            }



        });
    }
```

so when all the requests are done, I just want to console.log(mobilePhones);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be much easier to accomplish using [promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var myFunc = function (err,resp,body) {

if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var string = $('.author .mini').text();
    var regExp = /(\+971|00971|05)\d{1,12}/g;
    if(string.match(regExp)) {mobilePhones.push(string.match(regExp)[0])}
};


var p1 = request(urls[0], myFunc);

var p2 = request(urls[1], myFunc);

 // Do this for all of urls.length

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(() => { 
    console.log(mobilePhones);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = urls.length;
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    request(urls[i], function (err,resp,body) {

        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var string = $('.author .mini').text();
            var regExp = /(\+971|00971|05)\d{1,12}/g;
            if(string.match(regExp)) {mobilePhones.push(string.match(regExp)[0])}
        }

        count--;
        if (count === 0) doSomething() // all requests are done.

    });
}
```